# TimeSlider Tooltip Plugin did not work well

Tags: jwplayer

I have some HTML code and embed a video into JwPlayer 6. I found that when I try to mouse over to the timeline, it show me 0.11 and the image of the video at that time. When I click on it, the video will not show on that time instead of 0.09. I had try to encode my video with more key frames by using [QTIndexSwapper2](http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/) and [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) but it still no work. May i know got any solution to fix it?

Comment: @EthanLongTail actually my problem is similar to http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/feature-suggestions/32962/timeslider-tooltip-plugin

Comment: This is why I would need to see a link, as the Timeslider Tooltip plugin is a JW5 plugin only, and a native feature of JW6. I want to know which you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin is not compatible with version 6 of JWPlayer...
You can either
-remove the plugin
-use JWPlayer 5.x
-get the source code on github and adapt it so everybody can take advantage of it
https://github.com/francoismassart/JWPlayer-TimeSlider-Tooltip-Plugin